# Why classifier is removed from artifact while installing on local maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a utility project which uses gradle to generate the JAR artifacts. While generating the JAR artifact, I use `classifier` property of **Jar** task explained [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html). The code I use in my build.gradle is:

```
def artifactClassifier = project.hasProperty('classifier') ? classifier : "dev"
jar {
    classifier = artifactClassifier
}
```

I could see the JAR is generated as expected (`myutils-1.0-test.jar`) while I run following gradle build.

```
$ gradle clean build -Pclassifier=test
```

Now, I tried to install this artifact to my local M2 repo using following command:

```
$ mvn:install install-file -Dfile=/path/to/myutils-1.0-test.jar -DgroupId=my.group -DartifactId=myutils -Dversion=1.0 -Dclassifiers=test
```

This installation was successful, but when I checked my M2 repo, I see the JAR file is located as: `~/.m2/repository/my/group/myutils/1.0/myutils-1.0.jar`. The classifier value `test` is missing from the installed artifact name. Then, I tried to add this as a dependency as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>myutils</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <classifier>test</classifier>
</dependency>
```

But, maven could not resolve it. After I removed `classifier` tag, maven could resolve the dependency. Same thing happened with Gradle too. When I added following, Gradle failed to resolve the dependency (I tried without `@jar` and that too didn't work.

```
ext {
  myutils.version = "1.0"
}
compile "my.group:myutils:${myutils_version}:test@jar"
```

Whereas on removing `:test@jar` let Gradle resolve the dependency.

I am using Gradle `v2.3` and Maven `v3.3.1`

Am I missing anything? Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `-Dclassifier` (without s) as parameter to `mvn install:install-file`.

i.e.:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/myutils-1.0-test.jar -DgroupId=my.group -DartifactId=myutils -Dversion=1.0 -Dclassifier=test
```

Comment: @K Erlandsson, Thanks for the quick reply it works with `-Dclassifier` instead of its plural form. But then, maven documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html, is little misleading (they have both `classifiers` and `classifier`.

Comment: @Niranjan you are reading the wrong documentation. That is the documentation for the _deploy_ plugin. Check here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html for the install plugin.

Comment: @K Erlandsson, Thats a good point; my bad, I missed that. That said, from our Jenkins, we use `maven-deploy-plugin` to upload to our internal nexus repo. I guess I have to use same `-Dclassifier` instead of its plural and that should work. Thank you again.